# Java swing layout doesn't do what I'm trying to

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to write what I thought should be an easy to specify dialog, I have a few labels and a few text areas opposite them and then an OK and cancel button. 
In the middle I have a wide component  (I used a label for example)

```
 |label|  [combo box]
 |label|  [txtfield]
 |label|  [txtfield]
 |  long label here |


 [btn1]      [btn2]
```

I'm trying to use the GridBagLayout, it's not doing what I want, and I'm not sure I understand why. Basically I want the buttons to be anchored to the bottom of the dialog.

The code below shoes how I'm using it:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class GridBagLayoutExample2 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1972347726217162551L;
    final private JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("LABEL1: ");
    final private JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("LABEL2: ");
    final private JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("LABEL3: ");
    final private JTextArea txt1 = new JTextArea(" ");
    final private JComboBox cmb1 = new JComboBox();
    final private JTextArea txt2 = new JTextArea("");
    final private JLabel lblLine = new JLabel("a compenent on all the line");
    final private JButton btnOK = new JButton("OK");
    final private JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

    public GridBagLayoutExample2() {

        GridBagLayout bl = new GridBagLayout();
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(bl);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        int r = 0;

        placeComponentInGridBagLayout(lbl1, pane, bl, c, 0, r, null, null, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, null, null, null, null);
        placeComponentInGridBagLayout(cmb1, pane, bl, c, 1, r++, null, null, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, null, null, null, null);
        placeComponentInGridBagLayout(lbl2, pane, bl, c, 0, r, null, null, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, null, null, null, null);
        placeComponentInGridBagLayout(txt2, pane, bl, c, 1, r++, null, null, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, null, null, null, null);
        placeComponentInGridBagLayout(lbl3, pane, bl, c, 0, r, null, null, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, null, null, null, null);
        placeComponentInGridBagLayout(txt1, pane, bl, c, 1, r++, null, null, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, null, null, null, null);
        placeComponentInGridBagLayout(lblLine, pane, bl, c, 0, r++, null, null, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, 2, null, null, null);
        placeComponentInGridBagLayout(btnOK, pane, bl, c, 0, null, null, null, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, null, null, null, null);
        placeComponentInGridBagLayout(btnCancel, pane, bl, c, 1, null, null, null, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, null, null, null, null);

        setSize(new Dimension(850, 350));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void placeComponentInGridBagLayout(Component component, Container container, GridBagLayout bagLayout, GridBagConstraints c, Integer gridX, Integer gridY, Double weightX, Double weightY, Integer anchor, Integer fill, Integer ipadx, Integer ipady,
            Integer gridWidth, Integer gridHeight) {
        if (c == null) {
            c = new GridBagConstraints();
        }
        if (gridX != null) {
            c.gridx = gridX;
        }
        if (gridY != null) {
            c.gridy = gridY;
        }
        if (weightX != null) {
            c.weightx = weightX;
        }
        if (weightY != null) {
            c.weighty = weightY;
        }
        if (fill != null) {
            c.fill = fill;
        }
        if (anchor != null) {
            c.anchor = anchor;
        }
        if (ipadx != null) {
            c.ipadx = ipadx;
        }
        if (ipady != null) {
            c.ipady = ipady;
        }
        if (gridWidth != null) {
            c.gridwidth = gridWidth;
        }
        if (gridHeight != null) {
            c.gridheight = gridHeight;
        }
        bagLayout.setConstraints(component, c);

        container.add(component);
    }

}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Also is there a more modern way of achieving the same thing in Swing?

thanks

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what it *is* doing?

Comment: You are never forced to only use a single layout manager. For example use a BorderLayout as the main layout. Then create a panel using a FlowLayout for the buttons and add this to the SOUTH. Then create another panel for the other components which would go in the CENTER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a simple form, [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) is a useful layout manager. And to pack components on a line, it's useful to use [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

Here is a quick example:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
public class LayoutDemo extends JFrame {

    public LayoutDemo() {

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("label 1");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("label 2");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("label 3");
        JComboBox<String> combobox = new JComboBox<>();
        JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField();

        JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());
        formPanel.add(label1);
        formPanel.add(combobox);
        formPanel.add(label2);
        formPanel.add(field1);
        formPanel.add(label3);
        formPanel.add(field2);

        SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(formPanel, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3);

        JLabel longLabel = new JLabel("This is a longer label");
        longLabel.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        buttonPanel.add(button1);
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        buttonPanel.add(button2);

        JPanel basePanel = new JPanel();
        basePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(basePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        basePanel.add(formPanel);
        basePanel.add(longLabel);

        add(basePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LayoutDemo();
    }
}
```

You may want to use [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) to e.g. keep the `formPanel` at the top without stretching when resizing the window. But I hop I gave you some ideas on how to use SpringLayout for forms.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I can see is that your long label is going in the same grid cell as your OK button.
If you want the buttons anchored at the bottom of the entire dialog, try using a `BorderLayout`. Make a separate panel for the buttons and put that in `BorderLayout.SOUTH`. Then put your main stuff in another panel with the `GridBagLayout`, and put that in `BorderLayout.CENTER.` The buttons won't be perfectly aligned with your text components, but I think that's OK.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of borderlayout and gridlayout as shown below

[image]

```
package sof;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CustomLayoutFrame{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom Layout Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel centerPnl = new JPanel();
        centerPnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel gridLayoutPane = new JPanel(); 
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(3,2);
        gridLayoutPane.setLayout(gridLayout);
        gridLayoutPane.add(new JLabel("Label1"));
        gridLayoutPane.add(new JComboBox());
        gridLayoutPane.add(new JLabel("Label2"));
        gridLayoutPane.add(new JTextField());
        gridLayoutPane.add(new JLabel("Label3"));
        gridLayoutPane.add(new JTextField());
        centerPnl.add(gridLayoutPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        centerPnl.add(new JLabel("Long label should be going here"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(centerPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton("Button1"));
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton("Button2"));

        frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
}
```

Comment: The reason I wanted a GridBagLayout is to be able to have the screen maximized and the components still be reasonably nicely laid out, I tried your code, it's nice for the size you set,  but my size is (850, 585) ... I want the first 3 lables and controls at the top, the big lable to stretch to fill the width (same as your code) and the buttons to stay anchored to the bottom.

Comment: @Charbel: That sounds like the layout in my answer. Or what do you don't like about it? It would be good to give us more details, if it's not good enough.

Answer (score 2):

A nice `LayoutManager` for those purposes is the [`FormLayout`](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/) from JGoodies.